# Silenced error in symfony 2

Tags: php, symfony, caching

> WARNING - unlink(C:\wamp\www\Mdb\app\cache\dev\annotations\550E2C9.tmp): No such file or directory 
>           Context: {"type":2,"file":"C:\wamp\www\Mdb\app\cache\dev\classes.php","line":6380,"scream":0}

When I clear the cache or I dump asset they disappear but how can I prevent them from coming back ?

I think it's because of asset CSS link.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I just updated the version of SF and now it's ok. It was surely a bug in the core